# Usbmount won't automatically unmount device

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian, automount

I have RPi3 with raspbian. I want something to auto mount/unmout usb pendrives. I find `usbmount` which looks great with auto mount usb drives. `Usbmount` by default has 8 mountpoints (media/usb0-7). I noticed that if I plugin usb pendrive it always take usb0 path (if nothing is connected) but when I unplug usb pendrive and modify some files in it and again plug in it use other path (for example usb1) but it is same device.

I modify mount point and leave only "usb0" but then If I unplug usb pendrive and plug in with other files it just won't be mount (looks like usb0 is taken, and it's trying to mount on other point but there is no one).

So my question is why `usbmount` doesn't notice that I already unplug pendrive and release usb0 point but keep it used? There is solution fix that?